# How to build a Restful web service to fetch and process a file at a given url

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

What I want to do is, given a url to a csv file, I need build a web service that takes the url as a parameter, then download the file, parse data in the file and finally visualize the data in the file, The web service is supposed to be working on any given url pointing to a csv file. I'm trying to build the web service using JAX-RS right now. Any hints on how a little more detailed architecture that could work for this purpose? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so I will answer how you would do it. I've done this before with XML and NOAA Weather Prediction data.

1. Make sure the URL you are parsing from contains pure .csv/.xml data, e.g. [NOAA data](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=NDFDgen&lat=38.99&lon=-77.01&listLatLon=&lat1=&lon1=&lat2=&lon2=&resolutionSub=&listLat1=&listLon1=&listLat2=&listLon2=&resolutionList=&endPoint1Lat=&endPoint1Lon=&endPoint2Lat=&endPoint2Lon=&listEndPoint1Lat=&listEndPoint1Lon=&listEndPoint2Lat=&listEndPoint2Lon=&zipCodeList=&listZipCodeList=&centerPointLat=&centerPointLon=&distanceLat=&distanceLon=&resolutionSquare=&listCenterPointLat=&listCenterPointLon=&listDistanceLat=&listDistanceLon=&listResolutionSquare=&citiesLevel=&listCitiesLevel=&sector=&gmlListLatLon=&featureType=&requestedTime=&startTime=&endTime=&compType=&propertyName=&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2017-12-04T00:00:00&Unit=e&maxt=maxt&Submit=Submit). For testing purposes, it's good idea to download the .csv directly from the site and write code doing IO on the .csv file, but for once you're done with that, it's a much better idea to just read directly from the URL. I'm not sure what it's like for REST protocols, but for SOAP, the URL contains input parameters, so you can specify everything from the longitude latitude of a location, to date ranges, etc.
2. Use a CSV parsing library, or find a tutorial, like [such](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).
3. Store the parsed items. You could use a multi-dimensional array for testing, and transition to a database for long-term storage and processing.
4. Process/visualize the data. Once you have the data structure all set, you can then get creative with visualizing the data.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions in regards to that.

Answer (score 2):

Go and read some tutorials, this is a very general question. Don't expect people to write all code for your service. here is a tutorial link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/

and here an explanation about how to download a cvs file and save in java [Programatically Downloading CSV Files with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120942/programatically-downloading-csv-files-with-java)

here a nice tut about how to parse csv via csv http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: If possible, I would get rid of the downloading the .csv file, and directly parse from the URL. One less IO to deal with.